# Filter weekly from daily data and pick first occurence of the week

Tags: mysql

Assume you have a table with a stock time series on a daily basis.
Now you need to filter one data point per week, because you need weekly data for some analysis. You don't to have weekly averages, since this would leave much of the variation out.

This would be my initial approach, but it's not clear which of the data points falling in a given week is selected.

```
SELECT date, price from stock_series
GROUP BY WEEK(date)
```

1 How do I make sure it's always the first data point existing for a given week that gets picked?

EDIT:

2 If the above query stayed the way it is - which data point gets chosen every week? What's the MySQL logic in this case? Or is it just unpredictible?

Comment: guys, please also address the 2nd question i added in my main post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a better control over it, you could try using a subquery :

```
SELECT date,price
FROM stock_series
WHERE date IN 
(
 SELECT MIN(inner.date) 
 FROM stock_series inner
 GROUP BY WEEK(inner.date)
) GROUP BY date
```

I've added GROUP BY date in the main query because you probably have more than one entry per day, otherwise it could be ommited.

EDIT:

or try joining with it:

```
SELECT date,price
FROM stock_series
JOIN 
(
 SELECT MIN(date) AS innerdate
 FROM stock_series
 GROUP BY WEEK(date)
) inner ON date=innerdate;
```

Comment: i think the last GROUP BY date has to be left out, hasn't it?

Comment: Like I wrote, if you have only one price per date, then yes. As for the second part, I've found at mysql documentation: "The server is free to return any value from the group, so the results are indeterminate unless all values are the same." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Comment: i'm just trying your method on a huge dataset with about 10 joined tables and it takes forever to complete. It feels like it was running your subquery again and again. Do you know if the other suggestion by AndrewR without a subquery would also do the trick?

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation available at mysql won't confirm that - though I'm pretty sure it will work. Anyway, you could also try running a subquery as another join - I've just updated the above answer - it should be faster.

Comment: yes, in the meantime i have implemented a similar join to yours, which runs much faster. I also tested Andrew's solution and it seems to work ok too.

Answer (score 1):

You can order by date ascending, which should give you just the first result of the WEEK() group.

```
SELECT date,price from stock_series
GROUP BY WEEK(date)
ORDER BY date
```

Comment: is it really so easy? would be awesome if it was - can somebody confirm?

Comment: `WEEK(date)` returns same week for different years, you're better off grouping by `ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)/60/60/24/7)`